# Boost.Python Quickstart Failing

Tags: linux, boost, boost-python

I am trying to run the quickstart example [found here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/building.html)

I am able to follow the instructions all the way through 3.1.4 where bjam is invoked but the tests all fail despite that is IS successfully finding python.

[image: first of 9 similar error messages]

- I am on Ubuntu 16.04
- boost version 1.66.0
- Python 3.5
- gcc 5.4.0
- bjam 2014.03

Any hints as to what the problem is would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "Python 3.5" - the image says it is dynamically loading python 2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: @sehe was correct. It was using python2.7 instead of 3.5.